# In R, using one date column how do i subtract 2 spots above from the current line and in a new column add the result?

Tags: r, dataframe, datediff

I have a date column and I want to just use the information in this one column

```
      Date 
2020-01-05 
2020-01-30  
2020-01-20 
2020-01-10  
2020-01-15 
2020-01-30
```

I create a new column

```
df$3to1_difference
```

The function i want to create gives me this result. I would like to have the third column subtract the first column

```
    Date | 3to1_difference
2020-01-05  N/A
2020-01-30  N/A
2020-01-20  15
2020-01-10  -20
2020-01-15  -5
2020-01-30  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble::tibble(date = lubridate::as_date( c("2020-01-05", "2020-01-30","2020-01-20", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-30")))
tbl %>% mutate(`3to1difference` = date - lag(date, n = 2)) ## as difference in days

tbl %>% mutate(`3to1difference` = as.numeric(date - lag(date, n = 2))) ## as numeric variable
```

Comment: really helpful and appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl)[, `3toldifference` := .(date = shift(date, n = 3))]
```